# STL list very bad performance

Tags: c++, list, stl

It's supposed that "push_back" and "pop_front" methods of a STL list (implemented as a double linked list) should be constant O(1). However we were having cpu issues in an application running on linux and we found that "pop_front" method is incredibly inefficient when using lists. Is this a list implementaion issue or is the expected behaviour?

This is the example code:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { mA = rand(); mB = rand(); mC = rand(); mD = rand(); }
    u32 mA;
    u32 mB;
    u32 mC;
    u32 mD;
};

#define DELTA(t1, t0) ((t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec)*1000 + ((t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec)/1000))

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::list<A> l;
    std::queue<A> q;
    std::deque<A> dq;
    printf("Creating nodes...");
    std::vector<A> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        A a;
        v.push_back(a);
    }
    printf("OK\n");
    timeval t0, t1;

    printf("std::deque test: push back...");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (std::vector<A>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter) {
        dq.push_back(*iter);
    }
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("Done in %d ms, size = %d\n", DELTA(t1, t0), dq.size());
    printf("std::deque test: pop front...");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    while (dq.size() > 0) {
        A a = dq.front();
        dq.pop_front();
    }
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("Done in %d ms, size = %d\n", DELTA(t1, t0), dq.size());

    printf("std::queue test: push back...");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (std::vector<A>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter) {
        q.push(*iter);
    }
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("Done in %d ms, size = %d\n", DELTA(t1, t0), q.size());
    printf("std::queue test: pop front...");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    while (q.size() > 0) {
        A a = q.front();
        q.pop();
    }
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("Done in %d ms, size = %d\n", DELTA(t1, t0), q.size());

    printf("std::list test: push back...");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (std::vector<A>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter) {
        l.push_back(*iter);
    }
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("Done in %d ms, size = %d\n", DELTA(t1, t0), l.size());
    printf("std::list test: pop front...");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    while (l.size() > 0) {
        A a = l.front();
        l.pop_front();
    }
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("Done in %d ms, size = %d\n", DELTA(t1, t0), l.size());
    return 0;
}
```

For different number of nodes we get:

5000 nodes:

```
std::deque test: push back...Done in 0 ms, size = 5000
std::deque test: pop front...Done in 0 ms, size = 0
std::queue test: push back...Done in 0 ms, size = 5000
std::queue test: pop front...Done in 0 ms, size = 0
std::list test: push back...Done in 0 ms, size = 5000
std::list test: pop front...Done in 202 ms, size = 0
```

10000 nodes:

```
std::deque test: push back...Done in 0 ms, size = 10000
std::deque test: pop front...Done in 0 ms, size = 0
std::queue test: push back...Done in 0 ms, size = 10000
std::queue test: pop front...Done in 0 ms, size = 0
std::list test: push back...Done in 1 ms, size = 10000
std::list test: pop front...Done in 279 ms, size = 0
```

100000 nodes:

```
std::deque test: push back...Done in 5 ms, size = 100000
std::deque test: pop front...Done in 4 ms, size = 0
std::queue test: push back...Done in 3 ms, size = 100000
std::queue test: pop front...Done in 4 ms, size = 0
std::list test: push back...Done in 12 ms, size = 100000
std::list test: pop front...Done in 31148 ms, size = 0
```

Thanks!

Vicente

Comment: Things like this is *very* implementation dependent. Which compiler are you using? Which version of it? Which standard library are you using (some compilers allow you to choose), and which version? Are you building with or without optimization (benchmarking should always be done with optimizations)? And for the "pop front" tests, you are also testing and benchmarking the copy- or move-constructor of `A` along with the `front` function. Finally, are you building in C++11 (or higher) mode? Or using C++03 (or earlier)?

Comment: -O3. Can't reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f21df128b47920d

Comment: You should use std::vector by default and only consider std::list after doing a detail performance analysis. Bjarne Stroustrup has a note about std::list's performance here http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#list

Comment: @hungptit: Considering the queue behavior (push_back/pop_front), we know vector is pretty bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to check whether a container is nonempty, you should use `!c.empty()`, not `c.size() > 0`.

This is especially important for `std::list`, because in some implementations, `size` is a *linear time* operation, not a *constant time* operation.

(although, as vsoftco notes in the comments, C++11 strengthens the requirement on `size` that it really is constant — if you have a compliant compiler/library, you can try enabling the options to compiling for that standard or later)

Comment: Good answer! Starting with C++11, [it is guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) that `std::list::size` is constant time.

Comment: However, I've re-compiled for C++11 (add to g++ -std=c++0x or c++11) and I'm getting same results...Is there anything more that should be changed to use C++11 implementation?

Comment: @VicenteSirvent Which version of GCC are you using? Older versions (especially pre-4.9) didn't have full C++11 compatibility. Full C++11 implementation is only guaranteed in version 5 or later.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks for the reply. This was happening in a Fedora 20 distribution, will check gcc version tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

So, here is some practical answer: your tests are simply wrong.

First of all, your code is terribly C++03 style written, and utilizes evil C functions inside. you should use C++11 random generator, chrono functions and C++11 style range loop. only then a C++ developer can actually talk about your code.

Second of all, 5000 elements is **too small** number to actually conclude anything. try bigger number, like 1'000'000 and do the same test many times inside a loop. only then you can actually see the difference between different containers.

third, I doubt that `gettimeofday` is actually accurate enough to measure this kind of benchmark, you should definitely use some C++11 chrono functions or at least use `rdtsc` command on linux.

fourth, you need to isolate your tests. having one test testing **all** of your containers set is wrong. one test may cause the cache to fill up with hot data and the test that comes afterward simply uses this hot data having false performance boost. use different test for different container.

lastly, I do agree that generally speaking, a linked list is not the fastest container ever made. complexity is kind of a lier when it comes to actually speed up your code. complexity is a mathematical limit. it doesn't take into account real CPU architectures and simply assumes that everything is a fundamental step, which is wrong.

In a typical C++ application, the main two performance factors are:

1. Cache friendly memory (linked list is terrible at this)
2. number of memory allocations/deallocations (linked list is terrible at this)

list is very bad in performance because of these two reasons. you data is spread in non dense manner, which leads into many cache faults, and it also forces the application to result into many small memory allocations, one of the weak sides in C++.

Comment: Well, the solution is just "list::size() method complexity can be O(n) in some STL implementations and that makes the list iteration slower in the test". Test is just fine to show the issue and it's just an example. About cache/optimizations I prefer to avoid optimitazions to try to achieve the worst case scenario of the code and not depend on compiler.